# Wpf datagrid column header as Grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header

I have DataGrid with customized column like that

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="2*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/> 
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding OtherProperty}"/>     
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Const" Binding="{Binding ConstantValue}" />
```

As you can see, first column has double width of second column and contains two texblocks. So I need make header consists from two words. Every word above corresponding `TexBlock`. And I try to use Grid with two columns (because I have textblocks in two columns) as `HeaderTemplate`. I try to set `HeaderStyle`  like that

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Style.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                         <Setter.Value>
                              <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Header1</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Header2</TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                              </DataTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                   </Setter>
           </Style.Setters>
     </Style>
```

and I try to use `HeaderTemplate` like that

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Header1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Header2</TextBlock>
          </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

But in both cases I have the same wrong result. Namely. `Header1` and `Header2` placed togeter without any spaces like `Header1Header2`. And looks like `Header1Header2` has `HorizontalAligment`="Left" relatively whole header. 
I.e.

column border-->|`Header1Header2`***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**|<--column border

So `Header1` and `Header2` do not placed above corresponding TextBlocks in `DataGrid`. 
How can I solve my problem? How should I set `HeaderTemplate` to take what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would customizing the `ControlTemplate` work for you?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Header1</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Header2</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Your other option is to create your own `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` which will hint the available size to the headers. By default, headers' `ContentPresenters` won't be told the available size and will calculate the width from their content (`DataTemplate`).

In your case, the width is not set explicitly (e.g. `<Grid Width="200">`) so it'll simply be the combined size of the `TextBoxes`.